# What is the difference between the first two arguments given to a Haskell custom pre-processor when invoked using -F -pgmF?

Tags: haskell, ghc

From [GHC 8.6.5 User Guide $10.11.3](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-affecting-a-haskell-pre-processor):

> Use -pgmF cmd to select the program to use as the preprocessor. When
>   invoked, the cmd pre-processor is given at least three arguments on
>   its command-line: the first argument is the name of the original
>   source file, the second is the name of the file holding the input, and
>   the third is the name of the file where cmd should write its output
>   to.

I have tried to write an example pre-processor to see what is the difference between the three arguments passed to the pre-processor.

I have the following two files:

**Main.hs**

```hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF preprocess.sh #-}
```

**preprocess.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo $1 " -- the original source file"
echo $2 " -- file holding the input"
echo $3 " -- the file where cmd should write its output to"

echo "{-# LINE 1 \"$2\" #-}\nmain = return ()" > $3
```

When I compile the Haskell file using `ghc`, I get the following output:

```
Main.hs  -- the original source file
Main.hs  -- file holding the input
/tmp/ghc13496_0/ghc_1.hspp  -- the file where cmd should write its output to
```

Should the first two arguments be always identical? and in which cases can they have different values?

Comment: I bet they differ when stacking preprocessors.

Comment: @Carl Could you provide an example for how preprocessors can be stacked?

Comment: Enable the `CPP` extension, for instance.